# Child element 100% width of it's parent with overflow: scroll

Tags: css

I'm searching for a solution to get the child element 100% width of it's parent.

The problem: The parent has `overflow-x: scroll`. Text will insert a scrollbar. Now I want a child to get (the new) width of it's container.

Requirements: Pure CSS solution; no further HTML markup; no fixed width.

`width: 100%` will set it only to the init state width of the container.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y166e3nb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you wanted the child to be the width without scrolling or with scrolling, so I came up with both:

Without Scrolling:

```css
.parent {
    background: skyblue;
    width: 350px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}
.child {
    background: springgreen;
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    I'm a wide parent. My text-content will wrap my box.
    My child should get my new size as 100% width.
    <div class="child">
        I would go over the full width if I could.
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y166e3nb/2/

With Scrolling:

```css
.parent {
    background: skyblue;
    width: 350px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}
.child {
    background: springgreen;
    width:calc(100% + 330px);
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    I'm a wide parent. My text-content will wrap my box.
    My child should get my new size as 100% width.
    <div class="child">
        I would go over the full width if I could.
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y166e3nb/3/

The calc() statement in each needs to be 2x the value of the padding.

Comment: You should also be aware of [the browser support of calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Many Android phones wont support it.

Comment: I haven't used `calc()` so far. Works great! But sadly to many Androids wont support it...

Answer (score 14):

**I know it was told NOT to use more HTML markup**, but the chosen answer have some issues, for instance, if you extend the text of the parent, or if you change font-size attribute, the chosen solution will not work, **since it's doing a calc with a static 330px!**

So I decided to post what I think to be a better solution:

```css
.parent {
  background: skyblue;
  width: 350px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 40px 20px;
}

.parent > .content-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.parent > .content-wrapper > .child {
  background: springgreen;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
     This is some very very very very very long text to extend .parent div horizontaly, in      order to see .child divs extending
    
    <div class="child">
      This .child div should extend horizontaly
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of putting the text directly into the div .parent, we can create another div involving the text *(.content-wrapper in the above example)*.

Then we can use '**display: inline-block**' in this new div, **to make it respect its content width**, not the parent's one!

*...in other words...*

By adding **display: inline-block** to .content-wrapper, it'll **force this div to have the width of the largest horizontal content inside it**, in our case, the text!

Now if we add our .child div inside our new .content-wrapper, **the .child  will automatically fill the entire width of the .content-wrapper**, even without using 'width: 100%', because **every div element have by default 'display: block'**, which makes them have the width of its parent.

We should also use '**min-width: 100%**' in our .content-wrapper, just **to prevent it to have a width smaller than .parent's one,** in case of text width being smaller than .parent's width.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm searching for a solution to get the child element 100% width of it's parent

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This should fix it. But be aware, the parent width is 350 + 20 left padding + 20 right padding, so the child will only be 390px.